# Do people talk faster than they process?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, communication

I've hear both claims
1) people (in general) talk faster than listeners can process the meaning of the words being said
2) people can process what's being said faster than a person can talk

I think 2) comes from the fact that sometimes you can predict the end of a sentence before it is spoken. Have there been any studies that verify that people speak faster than can be understood or vice-versa?

Comment: This have to depend tremendously on what type of content is transmitted. Complex content with ambigous and unclear meanings would obviously take a lot more processing power than simple and clear messages. And it would quite obviously be very dependent on the listerners existing experience of the topic in question.

Comment: I voted to close this because it's unclear what's being asked. The question lacks sufficient definition and context to have a clear answer based on cognitive science.